# Chrome extension recieve message in the tab. chrome.tabs.sendMessage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a chrome extension, that can to this:

In my popup.html i do this:

```
$("#openLink").click(function () {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "GetURL"},
                function (response) {
                });
});
```

After this i click this button, i catch this message and create a new tab here: (background.js)

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting === "GetURL") {
        var tabURL = "Not set yet";
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: "http://google.de"
        }, function (tab) {
            //chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"});
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"}, function (response) {
            });
        });
    }
});
```

As you can see, i get the tab id and a try to send message to this tab. But how can i get that message in my content script? 
I use this, but it doesn't work:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        alert('s');
        console.log('s');
    });
```

Comment: You need to wait a bit, because now the callback runs before the content script runs. See `postData` function in [Chrome Extension Development - POST to new tab](//stackoverflow.com/a/23687543) and don't forget to declare your content script with `"run_at": "document_start"` in manifest.json

Comment: ...or you can inject your content script programmatically instead of declaratively using `chrome.tabs.executeScript` in your `chrome.tabs.create` callback, and calling `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` in the `executeScript` callback function.

Comment: Guys, please, give some more info how to use your solutions

Answer (score 1):

My proposed solution would be modifying your background script to [inject the content script programmatically](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#programmatic), like:

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting === "GetURL") {
        var tabURL = "Not set yet";
        chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://google.de'}, function (tab) {  //create tab
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'content.js'}, function(){  //inject content script
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"});  //send message to content script
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It worked! But i have this error in the extension: 
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: The tab was closed.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko how do i receive message to my popup js from background.js?